# Greatest value in group solution that also meets requirements for indexed view

Tags: sql-server, pivot, full-text-search, greatest-n-per-group, indexed-view

In an Azure SQL database, I have an EAV-style table **AttributeValues** that stores multiple attribute values, like this:

| Id | Organization_Id | Attribute_Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Old Org 1 Description |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | New Org 1 Description |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | Old Org 2 Description |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | New Org 2 Description |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | Old Org 1 Title |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | New Org 1 Title |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | Old Org 2 Title |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | New Org 2 Title |

These values need to be pivoted into Organization-specific rows, like this, which include the latest attribute value of each type (i.e. the top Value, ordered by AttributeValues.Id DESC):

| Organization_Id | Description | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Org 1 Description | New Org 1 Title |
| 2 | New Org 2 Description | New Org 2 Title |

The additional caveat here is that the working query needs to adhere to all the restrictions for an **Indexed View**, meaning no PIVOT, no CTEs or derived tables, no window functions, no subqueries, no outer joins, etc., because the Description and Title fields need to have full-text indexes applied in order to be used with CONTAINS() for search. Can this be done?

Comment: You might separate the concerns and use a history table for historical versions, or a Temporal Table.

Comment: No - it won't be possible to construct a query that returns the desired results and meets the [many restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) for an indexed view (e.g. Self-joins, OVER clause, Derived table, Subquery, MIN, MAX, APPLY, PIVOT)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need a "top 1 per per group" and then `PIVOT`/conditional aggregate:

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT Organization_Id,
           Attribute_Id,
           [Value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Organization_Id,Attribute_Id ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RN
    FROM (VALUES(1,1,1,'Old Org 1 Description'),
                (2,1,1,'New Org 1 Description'),
                (3,2,1,'Old Org 2 Description'),
                (4,2,1,'New Org 2 Description'),
                (5,1,2,'Old Org 1 Title'),
                (6,1,2,'New Org 1 Title'),
                (7,2,2,'Old Org 2 Title'),
                (8,2,2,'New Org 2 Title'))V(Id,Organization_Id,Attribute_Id,Value))
SELECT Organization_Id,
       MAX(CASE Attribute_Id WHEN 1 THEN [Value] END) AS Description,
       MAX(CASE Attribute_Id WHEN 2 THEN [Value] END) AS Title
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY Organization_Id;
```

As noted, however, you can't index a view on this. If you need an indexed view, you'll likely need to first normalise your design, and 2, look at history/temporal tables.

Comment: CTEs aren't an option in this case - this query can't be used in an indexed view.

Comment: Then the answer is "You can't achieve this" @coryseaman . Perhaps you should switch to a normalised design.